# .selectpicker('refresh') not refreshing bootstrap select on algolia places autocomplete

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, algolia

I am using algolia places to do a city lookup which then populates the state and zipcode for the selected result. The problem I am facing is when the state changes, the value for the bootstrap selectpicker is updated but the text is not.

I have attempted to use .selectpicker('refresh') but cannot get it to work.

```
<script>
(function() {
    var placesAutocomplete = places({
    appId: 'myID',
    apiKey: 'myKey',
    container: document.querySelector('#city-input'),
    templates: {
        value: function(suggestion) {
        return suggestion.name;
        }
    }
    }).configure({
    countries: ['us', 'ca'],
    type: 'city'
    });
    placesAutocomplete.on('change', function resultSelected(e) {
    document.querySelector('#state-select').value = e.suggestion.administrative || '';
    document.querySelector('#zipcode-input').value = e.suggestion.postcode || '';
    });
    $('#state-select').selectpicker('refresh');
})();
```

After selecting the city from the algolia places dropdown list of results, the state value will change, but it will still display the initial text, but if you click on the state select box you will see the new state is selected.

[image: results after selecting]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Researched documentation @ [SnapAppointments](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/) and discovered refresh was not what was needed, that only refreshes the list of items in a selectpicker.

Actually, you have to update the select picker differently: "*This is different to calling val() directly on the select element. If you call val() on the element directly, the bootstrap-select ui will not refresh (as the change event only fires from user interaction). You will have to call the ui refresh method yourself.*"

So instead of:

```
$('#state-select').value = e.suggestion.administrative || '';
$('#state-select').selectpicker('refresh');
```

You need to do this:

```
$('#state-select').selectpicker('val', e.suggestion.administrative);
```

This updates the selectpicker as if the end user clicked on it.